# AWS CloudFormation - output the name of AWS::Cognito::UserPool using !GetAtt

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, sam

Using CLI, you would be able to get the Name of the User Pool, but when doing it on SAM template gives you an error `GetAtt: Resource type AWS::Cognito::UserPool does not support attribute {Name}`

Any ideas? Can't find anything about AWS docs.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html

Provider Name is not the one i'm looking for. The one i am looking for is the name that displays when you browse User Pools on AWS console.

Comment: use `!GetAtt ProviderName`

Comment: i have tried that and its returning a different name rather than the name that is displayed on the user pool console. i think i specified it on my question that ProviderName is not the one i'm looking for

Comment: can you give your current result using ProviderName , and your intended result?

Comment: when automatically creating the resource name for cognito, it produces `AuthUserPool-XXXXXXXXX` , that is what i am trying to get. when you use ProviderName, it gives you `<region>_XXXXX` format, its not what i am looking for

Comment: !GetAtt resource.ProviderName = `<region>_XXXXX`,
`AuthUserPool-XXXXXXXXX` -> this is the one that i want to get

Comment: it's not possible. Not all attributes is exposed in `GetAtt` function. For cognito, it's only ProviderName, ProviderURL and Arn as mentioned https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html. So can you explain your use case further ?

Comment: what the result that you get if you just use !Ref resource ?